# iOS : Embed video in WKWebView stop music in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, uiwebview, wkwebview

I have an issue with `WKWebView` and the inter-app audio.
Let me explain the situation:

- I have an application like spotify which plays music in background
- I have an app which can open a webview (a `WKWebView`) and play video like youtube or just a sound.
- When the video or sound is playing in the webview the background music is stopped as well

I have already configured my app to be able to mix sounds, in my app, I have also a player and when I start my player the background music is not stopped.
Very weird compartment because if I use `UIWebView`, the background music is not stopped when the embed video is starting in the webview.

Why there is a difference between `UIWebView` and `WKWebView`? Have you ever had this issue? Is there a fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When the video is playing in the WKWebView at iOS10 the background music does not stop.
I think it's a bug...